# Django- 2nd App within project, page not found

Tags: python, django, api, url, url-routing

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong within the second app my project called 'weather'. The first part, 'home', works fine. I made it so that an empty url '' and a url with '/home/' both map to the home page. Even the link I created in my navigation bar to the home page works, but the same is not true for the weather link. I end up getting 'Page not found 404' Error.

Here is an overview:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8wdZ.png)

I included the app 'weather' in the settings installed apps.

Here urls.py file in the main project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from weather import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('', include('weather.urls')),
    ]
```

The urls.py file for my weather app:

```
from weather import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.GetWeather.as_view(), name='weather'),

]
```

The views.py for the weather app:

```
from django.views import generic
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City
from .forms import CityForm


class GetWeather(generic.ListView):

    queryset = City.objects.order_by('-requested')

    template_name = 'weather.html'

def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=c5a079de62bccff63d64ac8989f87e37'

    form = CityForm()

    cities = City.objects.all()

    weather_data = []

    for city in cities:

        r = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

        city_weather = {
            'city' : city.name,
            'temperature' : r['main']['temp'],
            'description' : r['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon' : r['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }

        weather_data.append(city_weather)

    context = {'weather_data' : weather_data, 'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'templates/weather.html', context)
```

The models.py for the weather app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    requested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-requested']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'
```

The weather.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<html>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
        }

    .head_text{
        color: white;
        }
    .card{
        box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
        }
</style>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
                    {% for city_weather in weather_data %}
                    <div class="card mb-4">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h2 class="media-left">
                                <figure class="image is-50x50">
                                    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{ city_weather.icon }}.png" alt="Image">
                                </figure>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="media-content">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <p>
                                        <span class="title">{{ city_weather.city }}</span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="subtitle">{{ city_weather.temperature }}° F</span>
                                        <br> {{ city_weather.description }}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</html>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is the blog.urls:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

I greatly appreciate anyone who took the time to read through this and help me.

Comment: This is due to, Django don't know where to go when you enter ' ' url. So at least change the path for one app. It may be `path('weather/', include('weather.urls')),`

Comment: Mubashar javed I tried this but I am still getting the 'Page not found (404) No post found matching query' Error.

Comment: can you paste your blog.urls?

Comment: sandeshdaundkar I just edited it into the original post.

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change either `blogs/urls.py` or `weather/urls.py` first URL match. It depends on what you want to see on your base URL.

```
# weather/urls.py

from weather import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('weather/', views.GetWeather.as_view(), name='weather'),

]
```

```
# blog/urls.py

from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

This shall resolve, assuming you want weather details on first page.

Comment: Ideally what I am trying to achieve is that `' '` and `'home/'` brings me to the first page, the blog application. I want the weather application to use 'weather/'. I noticed that if I modify the project urls.py file to show path `('weather/', include('weather.urls'))`, and the weather.urls file to show path `('weather/', views.GetWeather.as_view() , name='weather')`, I can access the weather page via http://127.0.0.1:8000/weather/weather/. Is there a way around this?

Comment: edited the answer., no need to change project `urls.py`, just change your `weather/urls.py` to above code.

Comment: @sandeshdaunskar After writing it just as you recommended, I am still getting the `/weather/` not found error.

Comment: what url you using?

Comment: comment this  `path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),` and check

Comment: that allowed me to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/weather/ but now it wont let me access http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/

Comment: why do you need `home/` when you already take user on post list page when he goes at `127.0.0.1` ? 
edit your urls.py file as above edited answer.

Comment: I see what you're saying. The home button on my navigation bar should redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ not http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/.

Comment: this is what my urls.py - blog looks like now `from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('home/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    #path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]`

Comment: yes, exactly! And you should remove home/ URL from `blog/urls.py`

Comment: check the answer and make similar changes.